# Static map not saving change made to object

Tags: java, rest, web-services, dictionary

I have been trying to change object in static ConcurrentMap from one restful service call and access changed object from another, but so far unsuccessfully. Details will follow with code.

**Restful service**

```
@POST
@Path("/nffgs/{nffg_id}/nodes")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public synchronized String addNode(@PathParam("nffg_id") String nffg_id, NodeType node, @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {

    DeployedNffgImpl changedNffg = NfvDeployerDB.getDeployedNffgSet().get(nffg_id);
    System.out.println("Size before: " + changedNffg.getResponsibleReader().getNodes().size());

    NodeReader retNode = nffgService.addNode(node);
    changedNffg =NfvDeployerDB.getDeployedNffgSet().get(nffg_id);
    System.out.println("Size after: " + changedNffg.getResponsibleReader().getNodes().size());

    NfvDeployerDB.getDeployedNffgSet().replace(nffg_id, changedNffg);
    return retNode.getName();
}



@POST
@Path("/nffgs/{nffg_id}/nodes/{node_id}/links")
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
public synchronized String addLink(@PathParam("nffg_id") String nffg_id, Link link, @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {

    LinkReader retLink = null;
    System.out.println("Size after: " + NfvDeployerDB.getDeployedNffgSet().get(nffg_id).getResponsibleReader().getNodes().size());
    try {
        retLink = nffgService.addLink(link, true);
    } catch (ServiceException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return retLink.getName();
}
```

Map itself is being initialized only once, with the service Constructor and addNode works perfectly fine, it changes the DeployedNffgImpl object as it should and within method change is visible. But when I try to access that same map from addLink, change is not visible, as if the object wasn't changed at all. Is there some logical mistace I am missing to see or is it something else ? 
If I missed to mention something, just ask.

Constructor of **MainService** which holds aforementioned addNode and addLink

```
public ServiceMain() {
    super();    
    if(!NfvDeployerDB.getInitialBoot()) { 
        NfvDeployerDB.initDB();
        NfvDeployerDB.setInitialBoot(true);
    }
    this.nffgService = new NffgServices(System.getProperty("it.polito.dp2.NFV.lab3.Neo4JSimpleXMLURL"));
    NffgReader nffg0 = NfvDeployerDB.getMonitor().getNffg("Nffg0");
    this.nffgService.deployNffg(nffg0);
}
```

**NfvDeployerApp**

```
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class NfvDeployerApp extends Application{

    private Set<Object> resources = new HashSet<Object>();

    public NfvDeployerApp() {
        resources.add(new ServiceMain());
    }

}
```

**NfvDeployerDB init**

```
public static boolean initDB() {
        if(initialized) {
            return initialized; 
        } else {
            deployedNffgSet = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
            NfvReaderFactory factory = NfvReaderFactory.newInstance();

            try {
                monitor = factory.newNfvReader();
            } catch (NfvReaderException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            activeHosts  = readHosts();
            vnfCatalog  = readVnfTypes();
            monitorNffgs = readNffgs();

            nffgNodesMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
            nffgHostsMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
            nffgNodeRelationships = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
            nffgHostsRelationships = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

synchronized does not really do anything, each request will create a new Class instance so it does not help.

The nffgService should ensure that the synchronization is there...

If you show how you create nffgService - it would likely point to the problem.

Comment: Synchronized is because of the currency with more than one Client using service at the same time. I have added creating of nffgService and other constructors.

Comment: you never set initialized = true;

Comment: When an request comes int o a RestfulService it creates the resources from scratch.  That way if you have any variable that is shared it does not get re-used.

Comment: Yes, it was the problem and I put @Singleton annotation and now it is working as I wanted it to. Thanks !